# How to sort only specific elements in an array?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of mixed elements, e.g. integers and strings:

```
ary = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]
```

and I want to apply a sort but only to specific elements. In the above example, the elements to-be-sorted are the integers (but it could be anything). However, even though they should be sorted, they have to stay in their "integer spots". And the strings have to remain in their exact positions.

The sort should work like this:

```
[3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4] # before
[1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5] # after
```

`"foo"` is still at index 1, `"bar"` is at index 4 and `"baz"` is at index 6.

---

I could partition the array into integers and non-integers along with their positions:

```
a, b = ary.each_with_index.partition { |e, i| e.is_a?(Integer) }

a #=> [[3, 0], [2, 2], [5, 3], [1, 5], [4, 7]]
b #=> [["foo", 1], ["bar", 4], ["baz", 6]]
```

sort the integers:

```
result = a.map(&:first).sort
#=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And re-insert the non-integers at their original positions:

```
b.each { |e, i| result.insert(i, e) }

result
#=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```

But this seems rather clumsy. I particular dislike having to deconstruct and rebuild the array one string at a time. Is there a more elegant or more direct approach?

Comment: I think you only need the indices of the elements that you want to sort. Why not sorting based on those indices ?

Comment: Is uniqueness of elements a guarantee?

Comment: @engineersmnky I just wanted to keep the example simple. It would be nice though if the solution would not rely on comparing / finding elements by equality. The sorting should (ideally) work as if only integers were in the array.

Comment: @Ely sounds interesting, can you provide an answer?

Comment: Curiously, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646258/ruby-sort-a-hash-by-order-of-an-array) posted earlier today. I will offer an answer to this question that is a variant of the one I provided there.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that question inspired this one. I was working on a solution as described above for the other question before the OP said the order and position of the remaining elements doesn't really matter. (my question is all about keeping them in place)

Comment: Turns out the earlier question was not what we though it was. See the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solution

```rb
ary = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]

integers = ary.select(&->(el) { el.is_a?(Integer) }).sort
ary.map { |n| n.is_a?(Integer) ? integers.shift : n }

# => [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```

Comment: This is so clean I am embarrassed. Although I would change this `select(&->(el) { el.is_a?(Integer) })` to just `select { |el| el.is_a?(Integer) }`

Comment: You could extract the selector as `prc = ->(el) { el.is_a?(Integer) }` and reuse it in both, `ary.select(&prc).sort` and `ary.map { |n| prc.call(n) ? integers.shift : n }`

Answer (score 2):

I am not proficient with Ruby. Though I'd like to take a shot at what I could come up with.
The idea is as evoked in my comment.

1. get the indices of the integers
2. sort the values of the indices
3. insert the sorted values back into array

---

```
ary = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]
=> [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]
indices = ary.map.with_index { |item,idx| idx if item.is_a?(Integer) }.compact
=> [0, 2, 3, 5, 7]
values = ary.values_at(*indices).sort
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
indices.zip(values).each { |idx, val| ary[idx]=val}
=> [[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 4], [7, 5]]
ary
=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```

Comment: I like this solution too and we can do it in a single chain via `ary.each_with_index.select { |e,_| e.is_a?(Integer) }.transpose.then {|v, i| i.zip(v.sort).each { |idx, val| ary[idx]=val}}`

Comment: Wonderful, it took some time to understand this. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that, as in the example, if `arr = ary.dup` and `arr` is modified `ary` is not mutated. If that is not the case one must work with a deep copy of `ary`.

A helper:

```
def sort_object?(e)
  e.class == Integer
end
```

```
sort_object?(3)
  #=> true
sort_object?(-3e2)
  #=> true
sort_object?("foo")
  #=> false
```

---

```
ary = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]
```

```
obj_to_idx = ary.zip((0..ary.size-1).to_a).to_h
  #=> {3=>0, "foo"=>1, 2=>2, 5=>3, "bar"=>4, 1=>5, "baz"=>6, 4=>7}
```

```
to_sort = ary.select { |k| sort_object?(k) }
  #=> [3, 2, 5, 1, 4]
```

```
sorted = to_sort.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
new_idx_to_orig_idx = to_sort.map { |n| obj_to_idx[n] }
  .zip(sorted.map { |n| obj_to_idx[n] })
  .to_h
  #=> {0=>5, 2=>2, 3=>0, 5=>7, 7=>3}
```

```
new_idx_to_orig_idx.each_with_object(ary.dup) do |(new_idx,orig_idx),a|
  a[new_idx] = ary[orig_idx]
end
  #=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```

Some of these statements may of course be chained if desired.

Answer (score 1):

### In-Place Re-Assignment at Designated Array Indices

You could certainly make this shorter, and perhaps even skip converting things to and from Hash objects, but the intermediate steps there are to show my thought process and make the intent more explicit and debugging a bit easier. Consider the following:

```rb
ary  = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]

ints = ary.each_with_index.select { |elem, idx| [elem, idx] if elem.kind_of? Integer }.to_h                                         
ordered_ints = ints.keys.sort.zip(ints.values).to_h
ints.keys.sort.zip(ints.values).each { |elem, idx| ary[idx] = elem }

ary
#=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```

The idea here is that we:

1. Select just the items of the type we want to sort, along with their index within the current Array using [#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index). If you don't like #kind_of? you could replace it with #respond_to? or any other selection criteria that makes sense to you.
2. Sort Array values selected, and then [#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) them up along with the index locations we're going to modify.
3. Re-assign the sorted elements for each index that needs to be replaced.

With this approach, all unselected elements remain in their original index locations within the *ary* Array. We're only modifying the *values* of specific Array indices with the re-ordered items.

Answer (score 1):

I will throw my hat in this ring as well.

It appears the other answers rely on the assumption of uniqueness so I took a different route by building a positional transliteration `Hash`
(Update: took it a little further than necessary)

```
def sort_only(ary, sort_klass: Integer)
  raise ArgumentError unless sort_klass.is_a?(Class) && sort_klass.respond_to?(:<=>)
  # Construct a Hash of [Object,Position] => Object
  translator = ary
    .each_with_index
    .with_object({}) {|a,obj| obj[a] = a.first}
    .tap do |t|
      # select the keys where the value (original element) is a sort_klass
      t.filter_map {|k,v| k if v.is_a?(sort_klass)}
        .then do |h| 
          # sort them and then remap these keys to point at the sorted value
          h.sort.each_with_index do |(k,_),idx|
            t[h[idx]] = k
          end 
        end
    end
  # loop through the original array with its position index and use 
  # the transliteration Hash to place them in the correct order
  ary.map.with_index {|a,i| translator[[a,i]]}
end
```

Example: ([Working Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/SortOnly))

```
sort_only([3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]) 
#=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
sort_only([3, 3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz",12.0,5,Object, 4,"foo", 7, -1, "qux"])
#=> [-1, 1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 3, "baz", 12.0, 4, Object, 5, "foo", 5, 7, "qux"]

sort_only([3, "foo", 2, 5,"qux", "bar", 1, "baz", 4], sort_klass: String)
#=> [3, "bar", 2, 5, "baz", "foo", 1, "qux", 4]
```

For Reference the Second Example produces the following transliteration:

```
  {[3, 0]=>-1, [3, 1]=>1, ["foo", 2]=>"foo", [2, 3]=>2, [5, 4]=>3, 
   ["bar", 5]=>"bar", [1, 6]=>3, ["baz", 7]=>"baz", [12.0, 8]=>12.0, 
   [5, 9]=>4, [Object, 10]=>Object, [4, 11]=>5, ["foo", 12]=>"foo", 
   [7, 13]=>5, [-1, 14]=>7, ["qux", 15]=>"qux"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code simply creates two new arrays: `numbers` and `others`. `numbers` are `Integer` instances from original array, later sorted in descending order. `others` looks like original array but number spots replaced with `nil`. at the end push that sorted numbers to `nil` spots

```
arr.inject([[], []]) do |acc, el|  
  el.is_a?(Integer) ? (acc[0]<<el; acc[1]<<nil) : acc[1]<<el; acc 
end.tap do |titself| 
  numbers = titself[0].sort_by {|e| -e }
  titself[1].each_with_index do |u, i|
    titself[1][i] = numbers.pop unless u
  end
end.last
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question here with yet another approach to the problem. This solution delegates most work to Ruby's built-in methods and avoids explicit blocks / loops as far as possible.

Starting with the input array:

```
ary = [3, "foo", 2, 5, "bar", 1, "baz", 4]
```

You could build a hash of `position => element` pairs:

```
hash = ary.each_index.zip(ary).to_h
#=> {0=>3, 1=>"foo", 2=>2, 3=>5, 4=>"bar", 5=>1, 6=>"baz", 7=>4}
```

extract the pairs having integer value: (or whatever you want to sort)

```
ints_hash = hash.select { |k, v| v.is_a?(Integer) }
#=> {0=>3, 2=>2, 3=>5, 5=>1, 7=>4}
```

sort their values: (any way you want)

```
sorted_ints = ints_hash.values.sort
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

build a new mapping for the sorted values:

```
sorted_ints_hash = ints_hash.keys.zip(sorted_ints).to_h
#=> {0=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3, 5=>4, 7=>5}
```

update the position hash:

```
hash.merge!(sorted_ints_hash)
#=> {0=>1, 1=>"foo", 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>"bar", 5=>4, 6=>"baz", 7=>5}
```

And voilà:

```
hash.values
#=> [1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar", 4, "baz", 5]
```